# Screen orientation for a firefox OS game using construct 2

Tags: screen-orientation, landscape-portrait, firefox-os, construct-2

I made a game using construct 2 and ported it to firefox OS.i want to play it in default landscape mode.I was seeing black screen up and down when i was playing it in portrait. Need help.

Comment: You will need to include your code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can force your application to be launch in landscape with JavaScript

```
screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
```

More information at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation#Preventing_orientation_change . Of course, you'll need to adapt your game to the new viewport.